# How to install RVM on macOS Big Sur with VS Code?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm

I'm trying to install any Ruby version manager, and then install Rubocop. "brew doctor" says my system is fine, and I recently upgraded laptops from MacOS High Sierra to Big Sur. (I'm on a new computer!)

I seem to have RVM installed correctly, and I have even tried and failed to get rbenv working. RVM is recommended by my software course for it's ease of use, and I'm following their notes, but here is my CLI code:

```
$ rvm --default use ruby-3.0.2_1
Required ruby-3.0.2_1 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-3.0.2_1"'

$ rvm install "ruby-3.0.2_1"
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/11.6/arm64/ruby-3.0.2_1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/log/1637203871_ruby-3.0.2_1: Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/1637203871_ruby-3.0.2_1/update_system.log: No such file or directory
Updating system - please wait
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-3.0.2_1',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1637203871_ruby-3.0.2_1/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

There's an old question and answer here that says the top part of my code isn't actually an error message, but I think the bottom part of it is saying I have some kind of issue.

Do I need to grant myself more permissions on this *new* laptop? Is the hint in the `mkdir` line above? Something else? How do I fix it? I would like to use an rvm to continue to use VS Code. I could switch to using AWS Cloud 9, but I prefer not to do that.

Comment: Try `rvm fix-permissions system` to the solve the logging issue. Compiling ruby might still fail for other reasons but at least you will know why.

Comment: Docs (limited): https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/help/fix-permissions.md